How to force Mathematica to evaulate some values of LerchPhi function?
Mathematica cannot give LerchPhi[1,0,1]=-1/2, LerchPhi[1,1,1]=0, and LerchPhi[1,1,1/2]=0, as they are divergent series. However, these values help give the right closed forms when used for some generalizations. So is there away we can force Mathematica to give these special results? The value LerchPhi[1,0,1]=-1/2 has been discussed in this answer. My idea is to denote LerchPhi[a,b,c] by l[a,b,c] or any other lowercase letter and express the generalization in terms of l[a,b,c], but for calculation purposes it's more convenient to use LerchPhi[a,b,c].
LerchPhi is the Lerch transcendent function. Thank you,

You can use
Unprotect[LerchPhi];
LerchPhi[1, 0, 1] = -1/2;
Protect[LerchPhi];

